# Unable to upgrade shell to meterpreter session

Tags: metasploit

I am trying to upgrade a normal shell to a meterpreter session using "shell_to_meterpreter" module. However, it does not work. I did not receive any errors after the module finished execution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j25Z.jpg)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j25Z.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try running `sessions -ls` to view your sessions and then `sessions #` where `#` number is the name of the session whose type matches meterpreter? i.e. `sessions 2`

In some versions of metasploit new shell sessions are set to background automatically. I am assuming this is also the case with new meterpreter sessions.

Comment: this is not what he was asking